# Difference between flink run -py and python run

Tags: python, apache-flink, pyflink

I recently working on learning pyflink, but I was a little bit confused. We know that pyflink table API convert stream/batch into table and do some work on it and finally sink to where u want. However, there are several ways to create table env:

For batch example:

```
t_config = TableConfig()
env = ExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()
t_env = BatchTableEnvironment.create(env, t_config)
```

and

```
env_settings = EnvironmentSettings.new_instance().in_batch_mode().use_blink_planner().build()
t_env = BatchTableEnvironment.create(evnironment_settings = env_settings)
```

but I found one of them only work for flink run -py batch.py, some other styles can be run as python batch.py for local run.

My question is what the difference of executionEnvironment and BatchTableEnvironment/StreamTableEnvironment, and when can use flink run -py and when can run by python interpreter with pyflink installed?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

The `flink run` way is used to submit jobs to run on the cluster. And the way of `python xxx.py` is to run the job directly in the local memory

Answer (score 0):

with `flink run` there is some configuration to set in `.sh`, you could consider the `flink run` is some bash scripts plus to the `python xx` itself.

for more information you could go to `$FLINK_HOME/bin/flink` or `flink-dist/src/flink-bin/flink`